# Getting the following TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'

Tags: python

Running this on Raspbian Buster.  I upgraded as per the instructions on cloud.ibm.com api docs:

```
Installing collected packages: ibm-cloud-sdk-core, ibm-watson
Found existing installation: ibm-cloud-sdk-core 0.5.1
Uninstalling ibm-cloud-sdk-core-0.5.1:
  Successfully uninstalled ibm-cloud-sdk-core-0.5.1
Found existing installation: ibm-watson 3.4.0
Uninstalling ibm-watson-3.4.0:
  Successfully uninstalled ibm-watson-3.4.0
Successfully installed ibm-cloud-sdk-core-1.0.0 ibm-watson-4.0.1
```

The script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
import json

text_to_speech = TextToSpeechV1(
    iam_apikey='7XT8Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    url='https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
)

with open('file.wav', 'wb') as audio_file:
    audio_file.write(
...
```

Again, the code block only includes the first line.  Not real helpful.
The almost identical script runs fine on Mint 18.

```
The actual error:
python3 watson.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "watson.py", line 7, in <module>
    url='https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_apikey'
```

Just for good measure I attempted to connect using node.js code and I get a similar error, "missing keyword apikey"

Thanks for any help.
Jim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 4, which you are now using, the `TextToSpeechV1` constructor changed to accept an `authenticator` instead of an `iam_apikey` to allow additional authentication mechanisms. From the [migration docs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/MIGRATION-V4.md):

> **Before**
>
> ```
> from ibm_watson import MyService
>
> service = MyService(
>    iam_apikey='{apikey}',
>    url='{url}'
> )
> ```
>
> **After (V4.0)**
>
> ```
> from ibm_watson import MyService
> from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
>
> authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
> service = MyService(
>    authenticator=authenticator
> )
> service.set_service_url('{url}')
> ```

In your case, `MyService` would be `TextToSpeechV1`.

Comment: Thank  you.  Apparently the documentation at https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python hasn't caught up with the source.  Or I'm looking at old documentation...

Comment: Oops no MyService found:

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'MyService' from 'ibm_watson' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ibm_watson/__init__.py)
Sorry for multiple comments.  This interface is not very friendly every time I try to get to a new line, by hitting enter, it posts a comment.

Comment: Like I said in the last line of my answer, it's not literally `MyService`, it would be `TextToSpeechV1` in your script. The API docs you linked have examples for version 3.4.0, not for version 4.0.